# How do I convert an illustrator vector file to a file readable for a clothing pattern software like Optitex

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I´ve created a sewing pattern in Illustrator and I want it to be readable for Optitex a fashion program software. The extension of this files is .pds, a kind of CAD file. I can´t find a way to convert or export the file specially since I work on a MAC and Optitex is a Windows based sofware. Can you help me suggesting what kind of extension will work for this purpose. Thanks a lot.

Comment: No clue about this, but you might try *exporting* the Illustrator file as a .dwg or .dxf file. Those are designed to be Autocad compatible.

Answer (score 1):

From the help: http://oldhelp.optitex.com/index.php/Import_from_Adobe_Illustrator_files

> Use the Import From CAD/CAM Files dialog in order to convert an Adobe
>   Illustrator type file into a PDS style file.
>
> Requirement: The AI lines need to be clean vector lines to define the
>   shape of the pieces.
>
> Import from AI files is available for PDS and Marker from version 11
>   only.

Answer (score 0):

This is from http://optitex.com/learn/

[image]

So, try to export as DXF. But with which parameter selections and what data you can assume to be able to transfer properly? Those unfortunately must be asked from Optitex. Probably you lose all flashy colorings, fills and strokes.

Optitex should have a quide for Illustrator users.

Comment: Thank u very much, if the DXF can be imported into Optitex that will be great! I only intend to transfer vectors, so I hope it will work.